# Google Earth Engine getThumbURL lifetime?

Tags: google-earth-engine, documentation

How long can I rely on the URL produced by `ee.Image.getThumbURL()` to exist?

I have looked through the documentation, but I cannt find details about their longevity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The authorization token lasts 2 hours. See: https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/image_visualization#thumbnail-images